# How to pass sed -n '4,$p' to sh command in jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, sed

I want to print specific line of file using sed in jenkinsfile but i have an error

I have tried like this

```
sh """
docker rmi \$(docker images -q | sed -n '4,\$p')
"""
```

I got error

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unexpected `,'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the `$` in the `sed` range doesn't have enough backslashes. You will get that error message if `$p` is being expanded to an empty string:

```
$ sed -n 4,
sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unexpected `,'
```

Try something like

```
sed -n '4,\\\$p'
```